# Find element by tag name within element by tag name (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I want to print all the href(links) from a website. All these hrefs are stored in an 'a' tag, and these a tags are stored in a 'li' tag. Now, I know how to select all the li's. I need a way to select all the a's within the li's to get the 'href' attribute. Tried the following but doesn't really work.

```
li = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for link in li:
     a_childrens = link.find_element_by_tag_name('a')

for a in a_children
     (print a.get_attribute('href'))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Tried the following but doesn't really work.` what it does mean?? is there any exception??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend css_selector instead of tag_name

```
aTagsInLi = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li a')
for a in aTagsInLi:
     (print a.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: This correctly selects and prints out hrefs on the page. However, not all of it. I think it has something to do with the fact that the href's im actually looking for are within a javascript page. I can see them in the inspect page but they don't get selected with this script.

Comment: @Jesse They might be inside an `IFRAME` or some portion of the page that loads late. You'll have to investigate and see since you have access to the page.

Comment: @Jesse As JeffC suggested, those missing links might be in IFRAME. I can help if you give us the URL of your application.

Comment: @Buaban im actually trying to gather every url from every game from the Unibet football page. [https://www.unibet.eu/betting#filter/football]

Comment: I already have a time.sleep[5] to enable the website to load properly. (Screenshot shows the whole page)

Comment: @Buaban Any idea?

Comment: @Jesse Sorry, I cannot access the web. It might be network policy here. I will try tomorrow when I get home.

Comment: @Buaban Ah no problem. Thanks. Let me know!

Comment: Got it guys! The links were actually stored in an Unordered List so i changed the above code to:

Comment: aTagsInLi = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul li a')
         for a in aTagsInLi:
             print (a.get_attribute('href'))

Answer (score 9):

Try to select the links directly:

```
 links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the right idea, but part of your problem is that `a_childrens = link.find_element_by_tag_name('a')` will get you what you're looking for, but you're basically throwing out all of them because you get them in the loop, but don't do anything with them as you're in the loop. So you're only left with the variable from the last iteration.

Your solution, correctly implemented, might look something like this

```
list_items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for li in list_items:
    anchor_tag = li.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    print(anchor_tag.get_attribute('href'))
```

That is, with the understanding that the HTML layout is as you described, something like:

```
<li><a href="foo">Hello</a></li>
<li><a href="bar">World!</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

**find_element_by_xpath** would do the trick...

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li/a/@href')
```