# Python Selenium: Difficulty finding the password element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to use Selenium for the first time to login to a website in automated fashion. I am able to locate the email (serving as a username) element pretty easily using this code:

[image]

However, for the password, there are no id or name tags, so I'm having difficulty finding that element. Here is the source code of the page. The password element is highlighted in gray below:

[image]

I have tried locating the password element by link_text and class_name with the following statements, but both have failed:

[image]

I imagine locating by XPath may be the way to go here, but I am unsure of the syntax (especially since there are so many div tags). Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Please post html and code as text, not as images.

Comment: There is a easy way to get the XPATH with google chrome, in the developer tools just click the element with the right click and select copy XPATH,

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do this using xpath after copying the xpath in the developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.password` is the `ng-model` attribute, not text.

`find_element_by_class_name` receives one class, you tried with three.

Use `css_selector` to locate the element:

By `request.password`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[ng-model="request.password"]')
```

By the classes

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this assuming there are no other password elements on the page would be to find all the input tags and then filter them to the ones that are password fields.

```
def getPassword(driver):
    inputs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
    for input in inputs:
        if input.get_attribute('type')=='password':
            return input
    return None
```

[Got syntax help from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022010/find-element-by-tag-name-within-element-by-tag-name-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password'][@title='Password']"))
```

Try to use less class selectors and use ids or tags. Classes can be associated with another elements. This is in Java, sorry. You can find it in python if you need it.