# How to get the iframe elements by TAG_NAME within a WebElement with style attribute set as display: none; using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, display, webdriverwait

I am using an undetectable Chrome Selenium webdriver in python to try and capture all `iframe` elements within the `div` tag with the `px-captcha` id. The html section I am trying to get from the whole page source looks as such:

```
<div id="px-captcha" role="region" aria-label="Human challenge" style="display: block; min-width: 310px;">
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="464ad1a7b7ed017f8c60542b859c5333648d76b8ec128a4f886c558900ffbe63dda2831825532a9be2d1f224eee47121e522391c7dcd7c55e86e1f17ebe944b7" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
    <p id="ejjpkyuhrAUbSZp" role="alert" style="color: #e50000; display: inline-block; margin: 0; vertical-align: middle;"></p>
</div>
```

I manage to get the `px-captcha` id with:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'px-captcha')
```

This gives me a WebElement from which I want to get all the `iframe` elements. I tried it with this but it fails:

```
iframes = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe"}
```

EDIT

The desired output is a list of the `iframe` WebElements similar to the type given by `element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'px-captcha')`

Comment: I think it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022010/find-element-by-tag-name-within-element-by-tag-name-selenium

Comment: I tried using CSS_SELECTOR and I get this `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe"}
`

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the descendant [***iframes***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) are having:

```
style="display: none;
```

sans one.

---

To get the count of all the descendant [*iframes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `presence_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'px-captcha')
print(len(WebDriverWait(element, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Is there any way to get this an a WebElement. The output is this: `[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {'ontouchmove': {}, 'ontouchstart': {}}, {}, {}]`

Comment: Or 10 if if include the print and the length

Comment: @geds133 Nopes, I'm not sure what you tend to mean through `{}`, `'ontouchmove': {}`, `'ontouchstart': {}`. But yes, you can print any of the attributes.

Comment: To explain, the point is I am using `ActionChains` to press and hold a button which I need an element for. I don't think this can be done without having the element. Does this make sense?

Comment: @geds133 IMO, using _`ActionChains`_ to press and hold a button sounds to be different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: I have the `ActionChains` and press and hold set up, I don't need that solution. What I need is the `iframe` element that has `'ontouchmove': {}, 'ontouchstart': {}` as a WebElement.

Comment: Let's say it's item 2 in the list, is there a way to get the 2nd `iframe`

Comment: @geds133 I don't see any `iframe` element that has `'ontouchmove': {}`, `'ontouchstart': {}` as a WebElement atleast within the HTML you have shared within the question.

Comment: _Let's say it's item 2 in the list, is there a way to get the 2nd iframe_: Sounds like a different question all together.

Comment: Sorry if I am being unclear, my lack of experience with this tool may means I am misunderstanding. What is that `'ontouchmove': {}, 'ontouchstart': {}` within the output?

Comment: As the question states that I want all the `iframe` elements but the output is a list of dictionaries?

Comment: `element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'px-captcha')` gives me a WebElement.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't accept this answer and it's not given me the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try that (Python):

```
        try:
            iframes = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')
            for frames in iframes:
                print(frames.get_attribute('....'))
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

(Replace '....' by what you want)

- Remeber "**find_elements**" is array, so you need a for or something like that.
- To interact with everything inside the frame you need:

  driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
- You can return to main frame with:

  driver.switch_to.default_content()