# Get every email of random pages

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get every email address of 1000 webpages using Python's Selenium.

My idea:

#### go to page `x`

```
a = driver.page_source
```

#### get the text of `a` that contains `@`

But however I cant get that part from `a`.

Comment: Check my answer, it should work. If it helped you can accept it to mark it as a working asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of the links this way:

```
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
```

where `elems` is a `driver.find_elements_by_...()` returned value, for example:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a') # You need <a> tags if you want to be sure to find href attribute
```

---

You can check if it's an email this way:

```
def isMail(link: str):
    if ('mailto:' in link):
        return True
    return False
```

So

```
mails = [link.removeprefix('mailto:') for link in links if isMail(link)]
```

---

I would suggest to read also [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862426/python-selenium-get-href-value/54862902) and [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022010/find-element-by-tag-name-within-element-by-tag-name-selenium).